# Where to specifiy the language of Document in HTML 5 when my page has two languages?

Tags: html, accessibility, w3c

This is HTML5 Skeleton

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bare Bones HTML5</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

If my webpage has some part in Danish and some in English then How I should define the language of the page in HTML?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can only define one language as the HTML's primary language. There can be only one language (no multiple values) specified for the `<html>` tag's `lang` attribute. But you can define a different language for some parts of the page.

For example:

```
<html lang="en">
...
<p lang="de">Ja, Deutsch.</p>
```

See the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes) for further info.

Comment: I normally start from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes , I try to avoid w3schools most of the time.

Comment: OK. But here mentioned that we can add more languages by adding comma http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-lang/#ri20040728.121940236

Comment: OK I found another link here http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-http-and-lang and according to this language attribute should be only used with <html>

Comment: That part talks about the HTTP headers, there you can specify more than one language, yes. But in your HTML, you should still mark the specific parts with the right language.

Comment: That charset is intended to work well with every language. But this is a new question I guess.

Comment: What to do if in same paragraph I have only few words in another language?

Comment: `They call themselves <span lang="de">Deutsch</span>.`

Answer (score -2):

You can define the language in html tag itself.
if you do following :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <title> ... </title>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

in the above markup code you defined "en" or english as your default language for whole document.